# Do not show me tags that I am not allowed to use

Tags: feature-request, tags

I just created a post on some meta site, and on clicking on the tags text entry and typing some text, I helpfully get a list of potential tags. Among them are those I am not allowed to use (e.g. the moderator-only [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)).

Comment: It's a trick to inspire you and everyone else to run in the next elections (it's a very sweet feeling when you [status-decline] for the first time ;)

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure this will fall under the "don't hide things from users" category. By showing it and allowing you to attempt to add it to your post, you get a nice notification explaining why you can't do that, and you **learn** about them, without having to go read some boring FAQ.

You may complain that it's confusing to show those tags when you can't actually apply them. Another user may complain that it's confusing they can't find the red tags in the suggestions when they type "status." You can't appease both parties.

Now, if you were being shown a blacklisted tag, that would be another issue.

Comment: Why would the non-mod complain? Why would they want to see those tags? If they really care about them, it is as easy as hovering on the tag and clicking on *info*?

Comment: @Tshepang: It doesn't matter why, it's that they *will*. You've taken the opposite stance, so you don't have the mindset of someone who would complain about that. **But there would be someone in that mindset**, just like there's someone with the mindset that they shouldn't be shown. I, personally, don't care either way, but I honestly don't see any good reason to change it.